# Apache Access Forbidden, Virtual host,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm tryig to run ruby on rails and redmine on xampp. My operating system is windows 7.
I followed this tutorial: http://nlb-creations.com/2013/06/26/installing-ruby-on-rails-and-redmine-with-xampp-on-windows-7/

When I try to access localhost:3000 I get this:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

This is my setup in httpd.conf:

```
Listen 3000
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#################################
# RUBY SETUP
#################################
<VirtualHost *:3000>
ServerName rails
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/dev-ruby/redmine/public/"
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/dev-ruby/redmine/">
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Allow from all
Order allow,deny
Require all granted
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#################################
# RUBY SETUP
#################################
```

I tried many solutions but none of them worked. I also deleted .htaccess file but nothing changed. Any ideas please??

Comment: Specify a [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)?

Answer (score 1):

If your document root in C:\ disk, you should change the xampp folder (and subfolders) permissions for your user.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed

Comment: Select "Full Control" checkbox.

Comment: Here is an example with screenshots. (http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7)